# What is the difference in "Day of year (y)" and "Day (d)" in VBA date functions like DateDiff?

Tags: vba, excel

I am unable to understand what the difference is between the "Day of year (y)" and "Day (d)" options for the `interval` parameter in the VBA `DateDiff` function.

In what circumstances (e.g. for what sample values of `d1` and `d2`) would the following lines give different results?

```
Debug.Print DateDiff("d", d1, d2)
Debug.Print DateDiff("y", d1, d2)
```

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code you tried, and the results you got.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, mind clarifying?

Comment: This is what Help says. You did read it first? *To calculate the number of days between date1 and date2, you can use either Day of year ("y") or Day ("d"). When interval is Weekday ("w"), DateDiff returns the number of weeks between the two dates. If date1 falls on a Monday, DateDiff counts the number of Mondays until date2. It counts date2 but not date1. If interval is Week ("ww"), however, the DateDiff function returns the number of calendar weeks between the two dates. It counts the number of Sundays between date1 and date2.*

Comment: *DateDiff counts date2 if it falls on a Sunday; but it doesn't count date1, even if it does fall on a Sunday.* From VB6/VBA/VBS help (same paragraph in all three).

Comment: paste code please, otherwise voting to close.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer.  (The original use of "Year of year (y)" had me confused until I saw the excerpt supplied by @ACatInLove, and then I understood what the question was asking.  And, to be honest, I would love to know the answer myself.)

Comment: FWIW - I just looped through all dates between 1 January 2014 to 31 December 2018, performing a `DateDiff` of every date with every other date, and both "d" and "y" options always returned the same values.

Comment: That is what help says it will do. They are BOTH days. If you were formatting one gives 32 for 1st feb and the other gives 1.

Comment: @ACatInLove So MS has just reused "number format" parameters of one function as the "interval" parameter for `DateDiff` and processes them on a "something similar to what you might expect" basis?  I guess that isn't an unusual thing for MS.

Comment: COM based languages (all MS non .NET languages) use COM. The VB/VBA/VBS/C++ etc use the COM date routines. They are a wrapper. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221554(v=vs.85).aspx for the COM call.

Comment: @ACatInLove P.S. It might be worthwhile writing an answer to say that, for `DateDiff`, both `"y"` and `"d"` are treated as an interval of "Days", but that for functions such as `Format` the `"y"` **is** treated as "Day of year" and the `"d"` is treated as a non-leading-zero display of "Day of month".  (If I didn't understand what the DateDiff documentation was saying, I can understand how a newbie wouldn't.)

Comment: @YowE3K I have done that

Answer (score 1):

`d` is day of month
`y` is day of year

`d` is actually well known as day of month. I have to say in 44 years of programming, doing accounting with and without computers, I have never seen day of year used. But in may be a cultural thing. In Australia you get paid and pay your rent fortnightly (every two weeks). None of the programming languages know what a fortnight is. There is also a luna month (4 weeks).

This is what Help says.

> To calculate the number of days between date1 and date2, you can use
>   either Day of year ("y") or Day ("d"). When interval is Weekday ("w"),
>   DateDiff returns the number of weeks between the two dates. If date1
>   falls on a Monday, DateDiff counts the number of Mondays until date2.
>   It counts date2 but not date1. If interval is Week ("ww"), however,
>   the DateDiff function returns the number of calendar weeks between the
>   two dates. It counts the number of Sundays between date1 and date2.
>   DateDiff counts date2 if it falls on a Sunday; but it doesn't count
>   date1, even if it does fall on a Sunday.

From VB6/VBA/VBS help (same paragraph in all three).

Microsoft Basics use OLE Automation functions. `FormatDateTime` uses `VarFormatDateTime` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221554(v=vs.85).aspx) which calls down into the Windows API for *International Features* such as `GetTimeFormat` (eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318130(v=vs.85).aspx).

For full documentation you need to read the docs at all three levels.

EG VB's `Msgbox` is a wrapper for the API function `Messagebox` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx). You can pass any of the parameters documented in the API reference or the header files and VB just passes it on. Only a few relevant ones are listed in VB's Help.

**Important**

Remember that the only guarantee is what is stated in the VB help file. That is the contract - you do what it says and it will do what it says in help. Generally it promises only one thing limited in details. All the above is implementation  details. You cannot rely on it. You treat VB statements as if they are a black box. As Windows changes your old programs automatically change with it.